# 新たな行に移らずに標準入力から文字列を読み込むには？

Tags: common-lisp

Common Lispで標準入力から1行読みだす関数と言えばread-lineですが，

```
(progn (format t "Your answer:")
       (format t "~A~%" (read-line)))
```

↑のようにすると，

```
<入力部分>
Your answer:<入力部分>
```

このように出力部分が新たな行に移り，入力部分と別になってしまいます．

```
Your answer:<入力部分>
```

↑のように直前の文字列に続けて標準入力を受け取り，出力するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: `(finish-output)` を挟めば良いかと。`(progn (format t "Your answer:") (finish-output) (format t "~A~%" (read-line)))`

Comment: @argus ありがとうございます！意図した動作になりました！

Comment: コメントで回答するのはやめましょう。また質問者の方は、コメントで解決した場合はお礼のコメントを付けるのではなく、その内容を自分で回答に転記して承認するとよいでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決済みのように見受けられたので解法を示します。

> ※コメントより引用
>   `(finish-output)` を挟めば良いかと。
>   `(progn (format t "Your answer:") (finish-output) (format t "~A~%" (read-line)))`